# Replace all Regex matches in a string which accomplish certain condition in C#

Tags: c#, regex

This is my text:

**text**=

```
 CREATE TABLE `t1` (
      `ID_B` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_IDBRIG1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_P`) REFERENCES `existing` 
      (`ID_PUEBLO`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
      `ID_B2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `ID_P` varchar(5) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT `FK_IDP_BRIG` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PUEBLO`) REFERENCES `nonexisting` 
     (`ID_PUEBLO`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
--
```

I want to replace all matches of "REFERENCES **word** " by "REFERENCES **word_new** " ONLY if word exists in a list, so it would be something like:

```
List<String> my_accepted_words = new List<string>();
my_accepted_words.Add("existing");
text = Regex.Replace(text, @" REFERENCES\s+`(\w+)`", "REFERENCES `$1_new`");
```

But it still **misses** the condition that (\w+) should match any item in **my_accepted_words**

Expected result would be:

**text**=

```
 CREATE TABLE `t1` (
      `ID_B` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_IDBRIG1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_P`) REFERENCES `existing_new` 
      (`ID_PUEBLO`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
      `ID_B2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `ID_P` varchar(5) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT `FK_IDP_BRIG` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PUEBLO`) REFERENCES `nonexisting` 
     (`ID_PUEBLO`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
--
```

I have an idea of how could i do it:

Apply a Regex replacement for each word in **my_accepted_words**

```
foreach  (string word in my_accepted_words)
{
text = Regex.Replace(text, @" REFERENCES\s+`"+word+"`", "REFERENCES `"+word+"_new`");
}
```

But what i would really like to do is somehow capture all matches, check if they accomplish the condition of existing in the List and replace/not replace according to it. Perhaps in the future i will need to apply more complex conditions.

Any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your words do not contain any characters which would be considered "special" by the regular expressions language, then you can build them into your pattern:

```csharp
string pattern = @" REFERENCES\s+`(" + string.Join("|", my_accepted_words) + ")`";
text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "REFERENCES `$1_new`");
```

Otherwise, you could use a match evaluator:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @" REFERENCES\s+`(\w+)`", match =>
{
    string word = match.Groups[1].Value;
    if (!my_accepted_words.Contains(word)) return match.Value;
    return $" REFERENCES `{word}_new`";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A MatchEvaluator can do this. It's a method that the regex will call when it finds a match, and it will pass the match so the method can propose some alternative value for replacement

```
    var text = "SOMETHING REFERENCES `old` AS WHATEVER";

    //instead of a list let's have a Dictionary that specifies replacements
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ { "old" , " REFERENCES `some_new_thing`" } };
    
    var r = Regex.Replace(
      text, 
      @" REFERENCES\s+`(\w+)`",
      m => dict.GetValueOrDefault(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[0].Value) 
    );
```

The last bit is the interesting part. It's a lambda that accepts a Match `m` - if the captured group value `old` is contained in the dictionary, the replacement value is provided from the dictionary. If the entry is not in the dictonary, the whole matched value is returned as the replacement (effectively a non-op)

If you want just "does the list contain X" then you could perhaps just have:

```
    var text = "SOMETHING REFERENCES `old` AS WHATEVER";

    var hs = new HashSet<string>(){ "old" };
    
    var r = Regex.Replace(
      text, 
      @" REFERENCES\s+`(\w+)`",
      m => hs.Contains(m.Groups[1].Value) ? $" REFERENCES `{Groups[1].Value}_new`" : m.Groups[0].Value
    );
```

It's important to note that you have to form the value you want: a MatchEvaluator takes a Match and should return a string that shall be the replacement, so you're responsible for creating the entire replacement in the "in list" or "not in list" case; that means either returning the original string (conveniently stored in `Groups[0]`) or an altered one. You can't return a string that e.g. contains $1

All in if you have a set of replacements to apply, it might be least confusing to not use a capture group and put the whole match in the dictionary:

```
    var text = "SOMETHING REFERENCES `old` AS WHATEVER";

    //instead of a list let's have a Dictionary that specifies replacements
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ 
      { "REFERENCES `old`" , " REFERENCES `some_new_thing`" }, 
      { "REFERENCES `new`" , " REFERENCES `some_other_thing`" } 
    };
    
    var r = Regex.Replace(
      text, 
      @" REFERENCES\s+`\w+`",
      m => dict.GetValueOrDefault(m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[0].Value) 
    );
```

Bear in mind that a confusion might arise fi the Regex is matching case insensitive, because the Dictionary lookup will be by default case sensitive; make sure they're aligned to avoid KeyNotFound errors